# How can I get execution time per step from within the Cucumber-jvm?

Tags: jvm, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

How can I calculate the execution time of each step in a Cucumber Scenario within Cucumer-jvm? I believe it's possible with the `--format` command line argument but can't find how to use this argument within Cucumber-Jvm

Comment: Hi I've edited your post to help people understand it better, have I kept the meaning of your post intact?

Answer (score 1):

Using cucumber-jvm, you can configure the way an individual cucumber runner class does the formatting:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags={"@debug"}, plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report/foo" })
public class RunCukesMarkedDebug {  
}
```

The latest version no longer uses format, but prefers plugin to indicate things like what formats to use. The html report doesn't include that information, but I think the json does. And if you want fancy reports, you can use the https://github.com/masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting-mojo maven plugin to transform the json output into a very detailed HTML report that includes timings.

Unfortunately for me, we can end up with a lot of screenshots when our tests fail, and that causes a heap dump in the json formatter, so we can't use the fancier report.